# How can higher-energy beta decays have 'higher polarization'?

Tags: radiation, polarization, chirality, helicity

The higher the energy of the particles, the higher their polarization.

I just cut-and-pasted the above statement from the chirality-and-helicity section of the Wiki article on 'Beta decay'.

What does it mean, exactly?

Are lower-energy negative beta decays more likely to result in a right-handed electron and left-handed antineutrino, which is the opposite of what normally happens?

Regardless, all decays are 'polarized' in the sense that the two particle have opposite handedness, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this as an answer so that it does not disappear:

I have been searching to find a formula for polarization in weak interactions and have only managed to [find this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-71689-8_107) :

> V-A-interaction is the resulting longitudinal polarization P of the emitted electrons with P = -v/c

So this would explain the statement you ask, except I could not find a derivation in a book or article by searching.

I will delete this  if something better comes up